# String always returns null in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android ,In an app I need to show a time in specific format for that I fetched the SQLite data which is in **"hh:mm:a"** format

So I trying to converted it first and then change the required format as **"hh:mm 
 a"**

But in my case the output string always returns null.

I need to done this in the RecyclerViewAdapter class

Code :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myAlarms myAlarms = myAlarmsdata.get(position);
        String mTimeSplit = myAlarms.getALARM_TIME();

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            Date date = myFormat.parse(mTimeSplit );

            String out = myFormat.format(date); // out always remains null

            SpannableString mtime = new SpannableString(out); //want to pass the string as "hh:mm a" format 
            mtime.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0);

            holder.mTime.setText(mtime);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }
```

Can any one tell me where I did the mistakes and how It should be ...

Comment: Where is the variable “time” coming from?

Comment: What is the value of `mTimeSplit` before attempting to format it?

Comment: Oh, you edited it just now, nm

Comment: @MattClark before it is format is "hh:mm:a"

Comment: @flopshot yes, it's a typo sorry

Comment: Where is 'dateFormat2' defined? Did you mean to call format using 'myFormat' ?

Comment: Yeah, obviously it’s coming from your myAlarms class not giving the right data because of improper design or the position of the alarm in the list. Let’s see the whole adapter class along with the myAlarms class.

Comment: sorry it's a typing mistake ,have edited now

Comment: @MattClark sorry ,it is a string data

Comment: @Nikson that does not answer the question. What data are you passing into the formatter? Not the format of the data, an actual working example of some data.

Comment: @MattClark  mTimeSplit  is a String (SQLite datatype is string )

Comment: If I were to type `System.out.println(mTimeSplit)` what would I see?!?!?! You have not provided a reproducible example. Of course I can't reproduce this passing in a value of: _string_. Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: @MattClark  "08:30:PM" this is the data I received in System.out.print (mTimeSplit)

Comment: @Nikson what about `date`? Is it non null before formatting?

Comment: have you tried using the debugger and step through your code? youll probably find it 123.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to see. So your problem is their format has `30:PM` vs `30 PM`, the formatter seems to not like this colon. If you read the docs for the [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) method, you will see how to get the index of where the error occurred. Most likely on the final semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problem with:

```
String mTimeSplit = myAlarms.getALARM_TIME();
```

It might not be returning the correct format. I have tried it passing directly and it is working fine.

```
public class HelloWorld
{

     public static void main(String []args){
       // String mTimeSplit = myAlarms.getALARM_TIME();

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            Date date = myFormat.parse("08:30 PM" );

            String out = myFormat.format(date); 

             System.out.println(out);


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

     }
}
```

Output:

```
08:30 PM
```

If you are receiving 08:30:PM then change the format to:

```
 SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:aa");
```

Comment: @Raj, OPs problem is their format has `30:PM` vs `30 PM`, the formatter seems to not like this colon.